# Flexbox - two column layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox, multiple-columns

I'm just starting with flexbox. I am trying to create a two-column layout.

I created the code below, which works, the only problem being that the containers `.menu` and `.content` do not strecht to the bottom when the browser window is resized so that scrollbars appear. How can I fix this?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .wrap {
      display: flex;
      height: 100vh;
      background: aqua;
    }
    
    .menu {
      width: 280px;
      background: orange;
    }
    
    .content {
      flex: 1;
      background: green;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="menu">
      child
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Content</h1>
      <h1>Content</h1>
      <h1>Content</h1>
      <h1>Content</h1>
      <h1>Content</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Well that's the purpose of using flexbox, it's working the way it should, the scrollbars will only appear if you resize less than the content otherwise the flex box will not show scrollbars, it's for responsive design

Answer (score 2):

Change the `height: 100vh;` to `min-height: 100vh;` on your `.wrap`'s CSS.

Answer (score 2):

You should change `height: 100vh` for `.wrap` to `min-height: 100vh;`
That way it will be *at least*  as high as the viewport (i.e. window), but adjust to the content if the content is higher than what fits into the viewport (since the default setting of `height` is `auto`, which you don't need to add):

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: aqua;
}

.menu {
  width: 280px;
  background: orange;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="menu">
    child
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Content</h1>
    <h1>Content</h1>
    <h1>Content</h1>
    <h1>Content</h1>
    <h1>Content</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```